# How do I pass class to server

Tags: asp.net, ajax, fiddler

Passing a single integer parameter from my client to the API on the server works.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult GetNextClients(int? clientID)
```

But passing a class does not.

Class defined here:

```
public class ClientParameters
{
    public int ClientID;
    public int FamilyID; 
    public bool IncludeFirstName;
    public bool IncludeLastName;
    public bool ExactDate;
}
```

Method:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetClients(ClientParameters param)
```

Data I'm sending looks like this:

```
    return {
        "ClientID": 5,
        "FamilyID": 12,
        "IncludeFirstName": true,
        "IncludeLastName": true,
        "ExactDate": true
    };
```

Running this from Fiddler hits my method and I get the class, but it is all default values.

I tried JSON.Stringify and sent, from the client and Fiddler

```
 "{\"ClientID\":5,\"FamilyID\":0,\"IncludeFirstName\":true,\"IncludeLastName\":true,\"ExactDate\":true}"
```

I tried adding

```
dataType: "json"
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

Still getting the default values.

Standard routing:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Quick gues: use properties, not fields in your class.

Comment: If you want to pass object to API, make sure your API method is a **POST** method.

Comment: @KrzysiekSzymczak  Thanks for the idea, but no change.

Comment: @YongShun My bad. I should have included that detail.

Comment: @BWhite are you 100% sure that you get default values? What I mean is that example you showed does not match 1-1 your model. Im model you have `ClientId` but you send `ClientImportID`. Then in FamilyId you send 0 (default value) and only that three books can indicate if you really get default value or not. Please, validate it again ;)

Comment: @BWhite if you still have a problem with that, can you provide git repo with your not working code, so I can take a better look at it ;) ?

ps. of course I mean bools not books ;)

Comment: @KrzysiekSzymczak Good catch. I tried to edit out all the extraneous details to simplify the question, but missed it on the stringified JSON.  It might be a week or so before I get to it because of this deadline, but I should be able to create a sample. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a C# API in .NET Core 3.1. The code is in the controller which is part of repository pattern with a service layer, all using dependency injection.

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult<T> Create([FromBody] T data)
{
  try
  {
    return Ok(_service.Create(data));
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    return BadRequest(e.Message);
  }
}
```

**Note** that you need the `[FromBody]` in your post request arguments

Look at the "Sending POST requests" section of the following link, to make sure you are formatting your AJAX correctly.
[Sending POST Requests](https://plainjs.com/javascript/ajax/send-ajax-get-and-post-requests-47/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why passing parameters never works for me, but it now occurs to me that I've run into this before.
I shouldn't have to parse it manually, but this works.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetClients()
{
    string value = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
    ClientParameters param = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClientParameters>(value);
```

Interestingly, it works whether I send contentType or dataType or not.
Also interesting, from Fiddler, it does NOT work if I stringify the JSON. Again, regardless of contentType or dataType.
Whereas, from the web client, it ONLY works if I stringify it.

Comment: Because when you parse inputStream on your own, the framework doesn't care what "content-type" is it as it doesn't have to parse it ;) It's your responsibility to parse it correctly (like your `JsonConvert...`);)